# Show data after selecting a value from a listbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to do this but using php and mysqli. It takes a value and show it below:

http://biblia.cartelesparafacebook.com/bibliajs/#/biblia/genesis/1

Right now Im testing this code, but I need help for achieve this. Please I going to appreciate your help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).on("change", "#name", function(){

        var elem = $(this),
            id = elem.val();

        $(".info").hide(200); /* HIDE ALL OTHER INFORMATION */

        $(".info-"+id).show(200); /* SHOW THE INFO OF THE SELECTED FULL NAME */

    });

</script>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    
<?php
require 'connect_bible.php';
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bible_books");
?>
    <select name="dynamic_data" id="name">
    <?php
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
        {
    ?>
        <option value="<?=$row["idbook"];?>"><?=$row["name"];?></option>
        <?php $i++; 
        } ?>
    </select>
        <?php mysqli_close($conn); ?>
        
        
<?php

$info = '';
require 'connect_bible.php';

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT idverse, name, chapter, verse, text 
        FROM bible_verses
        INNER JOIN bible_books ON bible_verses.idBook = bible_books.idBook 
        LIMIT 30");
        
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($idverse, $name, $chapter, $verse, $text);
while($stmt->fetch()){

    echo '<option value="'.$idverse.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    $info .= '<div class="info info-'.$idverse.'" style="display:none">
                  Chapter: '.$chapter.'<br>
                  Verse: '.$verse.'<br>
                  Text: '.$text.'
              </div>';

}
$stmt->close();

echo '</select>';

echo $info;
?>


</body>
</html>
```

I just tasting this code right now, but I need help for achieve this. Please I going to appreciate your help.

Comment: php runs **once** on the server and displays html, when you select you do that on the computer of the user, so you need to send the selected part of the bible via ajax to the server and the php script responds with the data, and javascript finally shows it on the user computer screen

Comment: Ok @nbk, What is the right code that I have to use to do that? Help me please.